# Why media queries doesn't apply

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I read all @media topics on this site and it seems that code should working

```
body
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px;) and (max-width: 2000px;)
{
    body
    {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px;)
{
 body
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

i have viewport tag, but still background is always yellow... What's the problem?

Comment: remove all `;`... like `(max-width: 1079px)` ... check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_bg)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here just take out the ;

```
body
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) and (max-width: 2000px)
{
    body
    {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1079px)
{
 body
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

[link to code example](https://codepen.io/apesyntax/pen/XWdBJbO)

Comment: @jacob-random, Hey if this helped you as a solution don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors you should try this

body { background-color: yellow; } @media screen and (min-width: 1070px) { body { background-color: red; } } @media screen and (min-width: 1080px){ body { background-color: green; } }

Comment: So where are these errors? U just put resolution in mobile first way instead of desktop first

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if there is a `<meta>` tag on the head part of your html document,
Without the tag your media queries will not take effect